Azure DevOps SQL Task: Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'currency' in table 'test' is specified more than once
I am trying to execute the following SQL script into the database. When I deploy it the first time, it succeeds without errors. When I deploy it the second time, it is giving the error.
I am not using an inline script in this case. I am making use of the task SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1  FROM SYS.COLUMNS WHERE  
  OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[test]') AND name = 'currency')
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[salesorder] ADD currency varchar(10)
END

I tried also
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = 'currency' 
              AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('test'))
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE test
        ADD currency varchar(10)
    END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'Currency kolom bestaat reeds.'
  END

What might be the solution for this in this case?

If you are using SQL DB, have you tried to run the same query in the Query editor without using pipelines?

I could reproduce the issue running the same query in the Query editor hub of my SQL DB, if the column currency  alreay existed in [dbo].[salesorder].

You may try the SQL script in the sample pipeline below, while we need to enable system.debug to check the output in the pipeline debug logs.
variables:
  ARMSvcCnnName: ARMSvcCnnWIFAutoSub1
  AzureSQLServerName: xxxxsqlserverxxx
  AzureSQLDBName: xxxsqldbxxx
  system.debug: true

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Run SQL query'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(ARMSvcCnnName)'
    AuthenticationType: 'servicePrincipal'
    ServerName: '$(AzureSQLServerName).database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: '$(AzureSQLDBName)'
    deployType: 'InlineSqlTask'
    SqlInline: |
      -- Check if the currency column exists in [dbo].[test]
      IF NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1 
          FROM SYS.COLUMNS 
          WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[test]') 
          AND name = 'currency'
      )
      BEGIN
          -- Check if the currency column exists in [dbo].[salesorder]
          IF NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT 1 
              FROM SYS.COLUMNS 
              WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[salesorder]') 
              AND name = 'currency'
          )
          BEGIN
              ALTER TABLE [dbo].[salesorder] ADD currency varchar(10);
              PRINT 'Currency column added to [dbo].[salesorder].';
          END
          ELSE
          BEGIN
              PRINT 'Currency kolom bestaat reeds in [dbo].[salesorder].';
          END
      END
    IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
    DeleteFirewallRule: false




@alvin-zhao-msft thank you very much for your time and help. I am now able to deploy the script.

So good to know and glad to help. Have a great weekend!
